# How can I make my custom infinte scroll more reusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a  custom endless/infinite scroll, which allows the user to load images as they scroll down.

How can i make this code below modular and easily reusable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Endless Scroll Flicker feed test 2</title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
        var perpage = 5;
        var currentPage = 1;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#photos").empty();
            $("#submit").click(function (event) {

                /**********************/
                var searchTerm = $("#search").val(); // get the user-entered search term

                var URL2 = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e58bbdc1db64c8f63ff7f7460104aa9d&';
                //tags=flower&text=&per_page=5&page=10&format=json



                var tags = "&tags=" + searchTerm;
                var tagmode = "&tagmode=any";
                var jsonFormat = "&format=json";
                var ajaxURL = URL2 + "per_page=" + perpage + "&page=" + currentPage + tags + tagmode + jsonFormat;
                //var ajaxURL= URL+"?"+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;

                $.ajax({
                    url: ajaxURL,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                    success: function (data) {
                        // $("#photos").empty();    
                        if (data.stat != "fail") {
                            console.log(data);
                            //$("#photos").empty();
                            // $("figure").empty();
                            $.each(data.photos.photo, function (i, photo) {
                                // $("<figure></figure>").hide().append('<img src="http://farm'+photo.farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+photo.server+'/'+photo.id+'_'+photo.secret+'_q.jpg"/>').appendTo("#photos").fadeIn(2000);  

                                var photoHTML = "";
                                photoHTML += " <img src='";
                                photoHTML += "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_q.jpg'";
                                photoHTML += " title='" + photo.title + "'";
                                photoHTML += "><br>";

                                $("#photos").append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);


                            });

                        }

                    }
                });

                /**************************/

            });

            $("#photos").scroll(function () {

                //var page=1;
                //var scrolloffset=20;
                //  if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
                // if($("#scrollbox").scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $("#scrollbox").height()-20) {
                // check if we're at the bottom of the scrollcontainer
                if ($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight())
                //if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10)
                {
                    // If we're at the bottom, retrieve the next page
                    currentPage++;
                    $("#submit").click();
                    //myAJAXfun();

                    //  scrollalert()

                    // console.log("page "+currentpage);
                }

            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*
    #container{ width:400px; margin:0px auto; padding:40px 0; }
    #scrollbox{ width:400px; height:300px;  overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; border:1px solid #f2f2f2; margin-top:150px;}
    #container > p{ background:#eee; color:#666; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:0.75em; padding:5px; margin:0; text-align:right;}*/
        #searchBar {
            align:center;
            position:fixed;
            height:65px;
            background-color:#777;
            border:1px solid red;
            width:100%;
            top:0;
        }
        #photos {
            position: absolute;
            left: 186px;
            top: 105px;
            width: 376px;
            height:550px;
            overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center" id="searchBar">
        <div>Enter Search Term</div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id=search />
            <input type="button" id=submit value="Search" />
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="photos"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap your jquery as a plugin. Here's a [boilerplate](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/) to help you refactor this.

You could then call your function as `$('#photos').myInfinteScroll();`

Anywhere you want to access dynamic controls I would then inject these into the plugin as options, so something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photos').myInfinteScroll({
       searchTerm:"#search",
       submitClick:"#submit"
    });
});
```

Allowing you to access these elements inside your plugin thus:

```
var searchTerm = $(plugin.settings.searchTerm).val();
```

and anywhere where you needed `$('#photos')` you'd use:

```
$element
```

you could also add some defaults thus:

```
    var defaults = {
        perpage : 5,
        currentPage : 1
    }
```

and even override them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photos').myInfinteScroll({
       searchTerm:"#search",
       submitClick:"#submit",
       perpage:6
    });
});
```

<strike>You could then [inject your css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505225/inject-css-stylesheet-as-string-using-javascript) so this would make your entire function callabled from inside the plugin and allow you to move it/use it on any elements you wish.</strike>

Forget that, just add the css as a dependency, also Jquery would also (obviously) be a dependency.